# Error when training an LSTM based model using Pytorch Lightning : RuntimeError: shape '[56, 1, 768]' is invalid for input of size 41472

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, nlp, lstm, pytorch-lightning

It has been several days since I am struggling with a **RunTimeError** when training an LSTM based model.

I am using `pytorche_lightning` module to create and train the model.

The produced error is:

```
RuntimeError: Caught RuntimeError in replica 1 on device 1.
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path/to/file.py", line xx, in function_name
    padded_hidden, _ = pad_packed_sequence(packed_hidden, batch_first=True)
  File "/path/to/torch/nn/utils/rnn.py", line 314, in pad_packed_sequence
    padded_output, lengths = _VF._pad_packed_sequence(packed_sequence, batch_first, padding_value, total_length)
RuntimeError: shape '[56, 1, 768]' is invalid for input of size 41472
```

Here are some technical details for the model config:

The **forward** function:

```
def forward(self, padded_embeddings, lengths):
        packed_embeddings = pack_padded_sequence(padded_embeddings, lengths, enforce_sorted=False, batch_first=True)
        
        packed_hidden, _ = self.lstm(packed_embeddings) 
        
        padded_hidden, _ = pad_packed_sequence(packed_hidden, batch_first=True)
          
        padded_logits = self.tagger(padded_hidden)
        
        packed_logits = pack_padded_sequence(padded_logits, lengths, enforce_sorted=False, batch_first=True)
        
        return packed_logits
```

The **init** function :

```
def __init__(self, cfg):
        super(Tagger, self).__init__()
      
        self.cfg = cfg
        self.lr = cfg.lr # 0.0001
        self.device_count = torch.cuda.device_count()
        self.class_report = ClassReport()
        
        # Setting the loss function
        if self.cfg.criterion=='binary_cross_entropy_with_logits':
            self.criterion = torch.nn.functional.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits
        elif self.cfg.criterion=='sigmoid_focal_loss':
            self.criterion = torchvision.ops.focal_loss.sigmoid_focal_loss
        else:
            raise ModuleNotFoundError        
        
        self.lstm = torch.nn.LSTM(
          cfg.embedding_dim, # 768
          cfg.lstm_cfg.hidden_dim, # 384 * 2
          bidirectional=cfg.lstm_cfg.bidirectional, # True
          num_layers=cfg.lstm_cfg.num_layers, # 1
          dropout=cfg.lstm_cfg.dropout, # 0.5
          batch_first=True,
          bias=True,
        )
        
        self.tagger = torch.nn.Sequential(
          torch.nn.Linear(
            cfg.lstm_cfg.hidden_dim + (cfg.lstm_cfg.bidirectional * cfg.lstm_cfg.hidden_dim), # 768
            cfg.classifier_cfg.features_dim, # 384
            bias=True),
          torch.nn.ReLU(),
          torch.nn.Dropout(p=cfg.classifier_cfg.dropout), # 0.5
          torch.nn.Linear(
            cfg.classifier_cfg.features_dim,  # 384
            cfg.tag_dim, # 14
            bias=False),
        )

        self.flatten_parameters() # Making computations faster
```

Comment: I don't know if it can help, but 41472 = 54 * 768 while your shape is 56 * 768. Probably the pad_packed_sequence function changes the shape of your function. Could you share it?

Comment: Actually I import it from torch.nn.utils.rnn, But here is its source code : 
https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/utils/rnn.html#pad_packed_sequence